# SiteMinder in Visual Studio IDE

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, siteminder

New to CA SiteMinder and understand the concept.  Currently we are using Windows Authentication and make use of `.IsUserInRole` in code as well as `<allow roles=` in the web.config.  The company is migrating to SSO and I need to understand how we will accomplish the same tasks without IWA.

I understand we will leverage "SM_USER" and other headers from SiteMinder but how will we do this in the Visual Studio environment?

I cannot seem to find good examples of how to get started.

Answer (score 1):

For getting the SiteMinder user id, you will need to extract the SM_USER HTTP header. The header should be simply from the http request header and can be directly used (SM_USER has the value that the user entered during login). In theory, you should be able to swap out .IsUserInRole with Request.Headers["SM_USER"]. 
Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks.  My question is more about how to simulate this in Visual Studio while debugging on my laptop?  I will not have any value while debugging for Request.Headers["SM_USER"].

Comment: The easiest way is to use a browser plugin that allows you to attach headers into requests. This way when you call your application's local URL, the header will be sent to it and the code should work. 
You can use Modify Headers for Firefox.
If however, you are looking to test without a browser, you should be able to use a mock request object with the header set in it. (for junits).
Otherwise, you would have to create a debug mode in which the username value can be hard coded.